# RequestAnimationFrame + Css3 Animation will caused Recalculate Style

Tags: javascript, css, requestanimationframe

I found that when running Css3 Animation and RequestAnimationFrame (without changing DOM) at the same time, **Recalculate Style** will be fired every time, It means GPU acceleration not working right? Is it a bug?

When only run with css3 animation, the GPU acceleration is working fine, everything is perfect.

[Performance - Css3 rotateZ only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhhII.png)

Starting requestAnimationFrame, will see `Recalculate Style` was fired everytime.

[Performance - Css3 rotateZ + requestAnimationFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QcT3.png)

Stop Css3 Animation (only requestAnimationFrame)，the `Recalculate` gone~

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cyhn.png)

Main code as followed:

```css
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateZ(359deg);
  }
}

.ring {
  display: none;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 24px auto;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
}
```

```js
const toggleCss = document.querySelector("#toggleCss");
toggleCss.addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.body.classList.toggle("loading");
  if (document.body.classList.contains("loading")) {
    toggleCss.innerText = "Stop Css3 Animation";
  } else {
    toggleCss.innerText = "Start Css3 Animation";
  }
});

let running = false;

function tick() {
  if (running) {
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
  }
}

tick();

const toggleRaf = document.querySelector("#toggleRaf");
toggleRaf.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (running) {
    running = false;
    toggleRaf.innerText = "Start requestAnimationFrame";
  } else {
    toggleRaf.innerText = "Stop requestAnimationFrame";
    running = true;
    tick();
  }
});
```

View the online example here: https://yfkyv.csb.app/

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-andras-yfkyv?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I have created an issue for chromium https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1252311#c6

Comment: I'm suffer the same issue. Do you have any workaround?

Comment: It seems that FF/Safari are affected as well (judging by the CPU usage when rAF and CSS animations are running concurrently)